# Which SSO method would be the most appropriate to have between a Spring Framework application and a Drupal instance?

Tags: spring, drupal, single-sign-on

I would like to provide a common authentication mechanism between a Spring Framework application (which manages the user database as well) and a Drupal instance. It is required that the group memberships of the user are reflected in Drupal.

I have thought of the following methods:

- OAuth2, but this is primarily for authorization so it has no standard way of communicating user data.
- SAML (can this provide information about group memberships?)
- An LDAP directory server (is it possible to expose an embedded LDAP server in a Java application so that an external app can use LDAP to query my user database?)
- Writing a custom authentication plugin for Drupal which calls a web service provided by the Spring component.
- Do you have any other ideas?

If possible, I would like to avoid the need for data synchronisation, so that the user database is only stored at one place.

Which method would be the most appropriate to accomplish this scenario?

Comment: Why not authenticate in either of the platform like in Spring with Spring-security and if the user is already authenticated, allow access in Drupal CMS. Role management can already be handled by Spring, you can always query Spring-security which will give back user's roles, and they can be mapped to Drupal. Because Drupal and Spring are inherently differently, there is no as such middle ground, you have to authenticate in one and use it in some other place whereever you want.

Comment: What do you mean under "allow access in Drupal CMS?" I think allowing access would require creating a Drupal authentication module which calls for example a web service which checks the user's credentials with Spring Security, and returns relevant user data (eg. group memberships). Or is there a more straightforward way to do it?

Comment: When the user is logged-in, spring-security maintains a session and its id for the user. If you create a method to get the currently authenticated user, you know already that the user is logged in, else you get a null. Once you know the user is logged in spring-security, you can login the user in your Drupal platform via creating an authentication module or whatever. You can also do the exact opposite, let user authenticate in Drupal, and manually login the user. Either way, somewhere you have to do something, no escape.